# div's not fading in on scroll

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbHdC/) and it appears to work fine, however when I implement it into a new blank project the hidden `div` s no longer fading in. Is there something I'm missing or not adding?

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
  <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
</div>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.hideme').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); 

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);     
        }  
    }); 
});  
});
```

Comment: Working in fiddle but not in your project??  Then you may miss to **add jQuery library**.

Comment: It's all there, I've even tried linking different jQuery versions. @Praveen

Comment: Your Coding language?

Comment: how about when you load the jQuery? could another file mess up how it loads? try putting your jQuery as the last import.